# Sorting an ArrayList based on a field?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Hi
I have an arrayList which has some objects.also my objects has two fields (1) name (2) cost
I want to sort this arrayList with its cost field.is there any special method that do it for me or I should  write it myself?also if there is some method for doeing this ,what is its time complexity(O(n),(O(nlogn))?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like type saftey (not using BeanComparator), then you need to write your own comparator.

e.g.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<SomeType>() {
    public int compareTo(SomeType lhs, SomeType rhs) {
        return lhs.getCost().compareTo(rhs.getCost());
    }
});
```

Note, this is not null safe (can cost be null?).

The other option would be to use BeanComparator, but make sure you add a test which makes sure that the sorting always works in case the method name changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Collections.sort()` method for sorting, if you implement the [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface for the objects which need to be compared.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/) for a couple of options.