# Sort an ArrayList of Complex Type

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I builded a class Couple:

```
public class Couple<E,K> {
    E first;    K second;

    Couple(E first, K second){
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
    public E getFirst(){
        return first;
    }
    public K getSecond(){
        return second;
    }
}
```

And an `ArrayList<Couple<String, Integer>>`

```
ArrayList<Couple<URL, Integer>> a = ArrayList<Couple<URL, Integer>>();
a=fillArray();
```

I want to sort 'a' by the value of the second element of the couple that is an Integer.

Comment: take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708707/sorting-generic-arraylist-on-a-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

your SimpleComparator

```
class SimpleComparator implements Comparator<Couple<URL, Integer>> {
    public int compare(Couple<URL, Integer> a, Couple<URL, Integer> b) {
        return a.second.compareTo(b.second); 
    }
}
```

your sorting

```
Collections.sort(a,new SimpleComparator()); // now a is sorted based on second value.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.sort(new Comparator<Couple<URL, Integer>>() {
    public int compare(Couple<URL, Integer> a, Couple<URL, Integer> b) {
        return a.second.compareTo(b.second); //assuming a.second is not null
    }
});
```